# SwiftUI 2 Xcode 12 Still No Voice Entry with TextField Nor TextEditor

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I had some discussion here on SO once before when I first learned that voice entry in SwiftUI
TextFields does not work. I am way more discouraged to find that voice entry in
iOS 14 TextField and TextEditor still does not work. In fact, the entire app crashes
immediately upon tapping the keyboard microphone button.

Since I believe that Apple truly encourages accessibility features, I have to believe
that I am missing some setup code to allow this feature. (I have listed microphone usage
in the plist file.)

I still use my own UIRepresentable UITextField and UITextView objects but it is truly
painful when these new objects should work. Here is a really simple example
with the new code.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var fieldOne = "This is the TextField"
    @State private var viewOne = "This is the TextEditor"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Some Heading").padding()
            TextField("Some text", text: $fieldOne)
                .padding(.all, 10)
            TextEditor(text: $viewOne)
                .padding(.all, 10)
            Text("After the text view")
                .padding(.all, 10)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
```

You can comment out any combination of the views - the behavior is the same.

The console reports the following just by tapping into the TextEditor:

2020-06-29 16:46:29.165522-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:604018] Creating client/daemon connection: 6B878753-D5E7-4010-8EF5-84494644E8B8
2020-06-29 16:46:29.239411-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:604018] Got the query meta data reply for: com.apple.MobileAsset.LinguisticData, response: 0

above several times

2020-06-29 16:46:29.424819-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:604018] Consumed extension
2020-06-29 16:46:29.428348-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:604018] getLocalPath asset com.apple.MobileAsset.LinguisticData 6ae6ca4a7a41d5047dbf34aaf85a12e0abda1448 local path is '/private/var/MobileAsset/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_LinguisticData/6ae6ca4a7a41d5047dbf34aaf85a12e0abda1448.asset/AssetData', exists: YES
above twice
2020-06-29 16:46:29.535571-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:604035] Got the query meta data reply for: com.apple.MobileAsset.LinguisticData, response: 0

above twice

Then tapping the microphone:

2020-06-29 16:47:45.331066-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:603711] Metal API Validation Enabled

2020-06-29 16:47:45.440014-0700 CheckTextTypesForVoice[1444:603711] -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setViewport:], line 2665: error 'Viewport Validation
viewport.znear(-1) must be between 0.0f and 1.0f
'
-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setViewport:]:2665: failed assertion `Viewport Validation viewport.znear(-1) must be between 0.0f and 1.0f ' -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setViewport:]:2665: failed assertion` Viewport Validation
viewport.znear(-1) must be between 0.0f and 1.0f
'
(lldb)

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 12.0 beta, iOS 14.0 beta

Comment: Did you try to submit feedback to Apple?

Comment: It crashes under the debugger, but it doesn't crash if you run it directly on the device.  The text field only gets the first character.  The text editor works correctly.  You should file a radar.

Comment: Well this is interesting. I did indeed try this on a device. It failed as described above. However, if I load the app and then stop the run in Xcode, then run the app from the device (not Xcode) as Paulw11 suggests, the TextEditor appears to work as expected. The textfield behavior is as before - one character, one beep and nothing more. I had filed a feedback on the textfield - Feb 15, 2020 at 11:04 AM – FB7582216. I received no reply. At least this is encouraging - looks like an Xcode bug but the intention is good. I guess I could abandon TextFields for TextEditors.

Comment: @user2698617 I share your frustration, [I really do](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX), but please bear in mind that this is the *first* developer beta, and all features/capabilities may not be implemented yet. Please file radars, and attach the FB number here - I'd be more than happy to duplicate it.

Comment: Vatsal - understood. Jun 30, 2020 at 7:06 PM – FB7832032